# problem with creating my first HelloWorld app on android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

these are the errors I receive;

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\AndyKhayaMhlanga\.gradle\daemon\helloWorld3\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
      > com/android/ide/common/blame/MessageReceiver

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 9s
ERROR: Unable to load class 'com.android.ide.common.blame.MessageReceiver'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try some of the things it's suggesting. I would start with syncing Gradle again: in Android Studio, do `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

This will make sure all dependencies download.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe when you launch a new app Android Studio automatically a TextView saying, "Hello, World" in the center. I this what you want to accomplish? 
If not, this has happened to me before perhaps going back to the first version or starting over would help. If you start over go step by step first the layout then snippets of code. And when it doesn't work you'll know what is wrong.
Hope this helps!